# Django Sekizai Template Tags in PyCharm are unresolved

Tags: django, django-templates, pycharm, django-sekizai

Pycharm usually auto-completes template tags like `static` or `block` yet fails to recognize the Sekizai tags like `render_block`. These are marked as unresolved. I've observed the same thing with djangoCMS tags like `cms_toolbar`. None of these tags are resolved, let alone auto-completed.

Even so they work fine it would be great to have them working well with PyCharm. All these unresolved messages are ugly at best.

Why are these template tags behaving like that? Is there a way to "activate" these tags in PyCharm?

**Versions:**

- Pycharm Professional 3.4.1
- Django 1.6.5
- DjanogCMS 3.0.3
- django-sekizai 0.7

Comment: I see this is a few months old but I'm running into the same issue with customer template tags within my Django project. They work fine when I actually run my code, but PyCharm doesn't seem to pick up on them, despite the use of `{% load my_tags %}`. Hoping this bump gets some visibility...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `sekizai_tags` is implemented in terms of `django-classytags` which does a lot of funky stuff with meta-classes etc.  I'm guessing PyCharm parses the text of the sekizai files (as opposed to importing them and inspecting the namespace), which makes it quite difficult to figure out what names are available.